# Problema al insertar datos en MYSQL con Codeigniter y Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, mysqli, codeigniter-3

Buenos días,

Lo que quiero hacer es que al pulsar "Enter" me inserte una nueva tag en la base de datos.

he creado mi archivo script.js:

```
$(".inputTag").keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:"../system/libraries/InsertTag.php",
            data:{ 
                'inputTag' :$(".inputTag").val()
            },
            success:function(){
                alert("hecho");

            },
            error:function(){
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Pero recibo el siguiente error:

> ```
> POST http://localhost/MIAPP/system/libraries/InsertTag.php 403 (Forbidden)
> ```

¿Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal y como arreglarlo?  Supongo que mi problema está en que no suelo usar codeigniter porque esto sin él funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo InserTag es una libreria, ya que esta ubicado dentro de dicha carpeta, creo que el problema esta en que accedes a la librería directamente. Deberías crear un controlador que se encargue de gestionar las operaciones de la librería y desde allí llamar a la librería con

```
$this->load->library('InsertTag').
```

Es que como no se si utilizas la funcionalidad que hay en la librería en otros sitios... porque si sólo utilizas InserTag para este ajax, puedes quitar InserTag de la librería y crearlo como controlador.

Un controlador se puede llamar directamente desde ajax pero una librería no.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter no permite acceder a los directorios ni archivos de la carpeta system directamente, tu url es `../system/libraries/InsertTag.php`, por lo que no podrás acceder directamente a tu librería, Codeigniter sigue el patrón MVC, por lo que las llamadas a tus librerías deberías hacerlas desde un controlador.

Suponiendo que tu librería es `InsertTag.php`, se recomienda colocar las librerías en el directorio `application/libraries/`, luego la cargas en tu controlador con:

```
$this->load->library('InsertTag').
```

Answer (score 0):

Que tal como comenta @Juan Pizon, codegnaiter maneja el modelo MVC (Movel, view, controller).

en tu ajax en el url:"funcionDeTuControlador". Tiene que existir un la función en tu controlador.php, que esta en la carpeta **applications/controllers/controlador.php**.

ejemplo LLamado ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                type:"POST",  
                dataType:"json",
                url:"nombreFuncionDeTuControlador",
                data:'inputTag' :$(".inputTag").val(),
                success:function(data){
                  alert("ok: "+data);
                },error: function(data){
                    console.error(data);            
                }       
            });
```

Ejemplo código en controlador recuerda la ruta de las carpetas de tu proyecto en codegnaiter por lo regular todos tiene el mismo nombre al menos que la cambies **(applications/controllers/controlador.php.)**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class controlador extends CI_Controller {
    public function nombreFuncionDeTuControlador(){
     //y aqui obtienes los valores que envias del form
     $valorExtraido = $this->input->post("inputTag");
   //o puedes usar la forma tradicional
  $valorExtraido = $_POST["inputTag"];
   echo "ok"
     } 
}
?>
```

todo esto por el modelo MVC que maneja codegnaiter.

de echo puedes invocar la función desde la url
http://localhost/controlador/nombreFuncionDeTuControlador

Y una cosa al momento de que obtienes el valor de un input te recomiendo que uses el id del elmento ya que utiliaste la class $(".inputTag").val() con id $("#inputTag").val()
ya que el id es único y un class se utiliza en diferentes áreas y se usa mas para estilos que de igual forma se puede en jquery puede acceder a elementos html con el class pero para un form es recomendable el id de tu input .

Espero te sirva la información saludos.